# Where to add the images physically in the Xamarin-forms application?

Tags: xamarin.forms

How and where to physically add images into a Xamarin crossplatform solution ? I have a WPF project + android + iOS projects and I have a listview control in the MainPage.xaml (in the WPF project). Each listviewitem should show an image and a text description. But I don't know how and where to physically put images in the Xamarin project explorer ? I am asking for the physical location in the solution explorer. I am using VS2019.

I am planning to show these item images in the XAML. Please throw some light on this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: please read the docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#local-images

Comment: @Jason i added a folder named "Images" in the WPF project and added the images into that folder and I added images into the Resource/Drawable folder in the Android project. Now the issue is how to access those images in the WPF databinding with listview ?

Comment: the docs I linked to explain how to do this

Comment: If I understand you last comment correctly, you have worked out where to put the images from the docs but now you need to access them from code? If you have an Image Source then load them in with ImageSource.FromFile(...) inserting the name of your resource without its extension. If you have your images in the correct locations then the system will choose the correct density for you.